# Simple Twitter Login with Rails and Email confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, twitter-oauth

I'm pretty new to Rails and trying to create a simple login with Twitter only.

It seems like Devise is the way to go and it works indeed with the [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-devise-and-omniauth-for-your-rails-application) I followed.
But since Twitter does not pass the user's email address, I need to ask the user for it. But how can I achieve that?

The workflow would be as follows:

1. User signs up with Twitter
2. User is redirected to an form and enters her email
3. Confirmation mail is sent
4. User clicks on the link and the account is ready to use.

Step 1 does already work. However, how can I achieve the rest of it as well?

Thank you guys

**Edit**

Well...whatever. I switched to Node.js which I feel much more comfortable with. Node FTW!

Comment: http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/ this is good source, I tried it out recently. This has step 2, later steps you can complete off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe the solution you are looking for:
http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/

hth,

Ian.